# Cannot get data from dynamic input fields using foreach loop in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have multiple multiple input fields in my form that are being created dynamically,
Now there are two sets one is attribute and the other is attribute values like this:

```
<input type="text" name="attribute_name[attr_1]" placeholder="Attribute Name" class="form-control" required="">

<input type="text" name="attribute_value[][attr_1]" placeholder="Attribute Value" class="form-control" required="">

<input type="text" name="attribute_value[][attr_1]" placeholder="Attribute Value" class="form-control" required="">

<input type="text" name="attribute_name[attr_2]" placeholder="Attribute Name" class="form-control" required="">

<input type="text" name="attribute_value[][attr_2]" placeholder="Attribute Value" class="form-control" required="">

<input type="text" name="attribute_value[][attr_2]" placeholder="Attribute Value" class="form-control" required="">
```

Now using foreach loop, first i want to get all the attribute fields, then in the inner loop i want to am getting the attribute values like in the code below:

```
foreach($request->input('attribute_name') as $attrKey => $val)
{
    foreach ($request->input('attribute_value.*.'.$attrKey)  as $attr_valKey => $value) {
        $attribute_value=$value;
    }
}
```

> $request->input('attribute_name') contains Array ( [attr_1] => Color
> [attr_2] => Size )

The concept i'm using is i don't know the key because it is dynamic, so i'm first trying to loop through all the attribute name one by one and then in the inner loop extract attribute values.

For first time i'm getting the attribute and its related value for second attribute, i didn't get any value.

Comment: Did the below answer solve your issue or are you still having problems?

Comment: @Rwd: Thanks , your solution worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure exactly what the end goal is so I may be off the mark.

The way you have it at the minute:

```
$request->input('attribute_value.*.' . $attrKey)
```

would include all of the `attribute_value[][...]` fields, however, the values that are not related to the `$attrKey` will be `null`.

It might be an idea to change `attribute_value[][attr_1]` to `attribute_value[attr_1][]`.

This would mean that you foreach loop would look something like:

```
foreach ($request->input('attribute_name') as $attrKey => $val) {
    foreach ($request->input('attribute_value.' . $attrKey) as $attr_valKey => $value) {
        $attribute_value = $value;
    }
}
```

`$request->input('attribute_value.' . $attrKey)` would only contain the values that actual relate to `$attrKey`.